# Find a basis of W⊥

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

[image]

I'm stuck with this problem. I pulled apart x and y so x = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} and y = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} and set them up for addition. I did the process for finding the orthogonal components, then I added them back together and I got a solution of \begin{bmatrix}1/2\\-1/2\\1\end{bmatrix} and the answer is incorrect. How is this solved?

Comment: You're using language incorrectly.  It's not true that $x = (0,1,1)$.  $x$ is a number, not a vector.  Is there a reason you expected that "adding the vectors together" would give you the answer you need?

Comment: You seem to be struggling with the basic definitions.  Do you know what a basis is?  If you have a matrix, do you know how to find a basis of its nullspace or column space?  For a space $W$, do you know what $W^\perp$ means?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, in all honesty, it's what my tutor said to do and we worked this out together and clearly the answer is incorrect. From there, she said she didn't know how else to figure it out. She stated that adding them back together would create the basis, that's where the addition comes from.

I understand the concept of a basis and how to figure those out. However, when it comes to variables instead of numbers, I get really confused and thrown off. I know that W⊥ is the orthogonal complement of W.

Comment: All right, let's start from here then: do you know how to find a basis for the nullspace of a matrix?

Comment: Reduce the matrix to RREF. From there, put the resulting matrix into PVF and then pull out the free variables to basically multiply by the corresponding values found in the PVF form.  

I hope this makes sense, I am terrible with explaining things. I tried translating from my notes I have.

Comment: that's all right, I was really just looking for a "yes" or "no" there.  I'll put an answer together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** As you (sort of) said, $W$ is the space spanned by the vectors
$$
v_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\1}, \quad v_2 = \pmatrix{0\\1\\1}
$$
in particular, $W$ is the set of all vectors of the form $xv_1 + yv_2$.  Now, if a vector $u = (u_1,u_2,u_3)$ is in $W^\perp$, the *orthogonal complement* of $W$, then $u$ must be orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$.  In particular, we must have $v_1^Tu = 0$ and $v_2^Tu = 0$ ($v^Tu$ is the dot-product of $v$ and $u$).  Writing out the equations, we have
$$
(1)u_1 + (0)u_2 + (1)u_3 = 0\\
(0)u_1 + (1)u_2 + (1)u_3 = 0
$$
which is to say that 
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&1\\0&1&1} \pmatrix{u_1\\u_2\\u_3} = \pmatrix{0\\0}
$$
in other words, the orthogonal complement $W^\perp$ is exactly the same as the nullspace of the marix
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&1\\0&1&1}
$$
so, what you need to do is find a basis for the nullspace of this matrix (which is already in RREF).

Answer (score 1):

One answer is (-1,-1,1). You can assume that (p,q,r) is orthogonal to both (1,0,1) and (1,1,0) and you will get the relation between p,q,r.